Is $G$ Hamiltonian?
Below is a graph, $G$. I believe it is non-Hamiltonian, but I am unsure of how to verify this. I know that for any graph, if there is a positive integer n such that removing n vertices yields a graph with more than n components, then the graph is not Hamiltonian, but I cannot find such set of vertices. 

Hint: it is Hamiltonian.

It is Eulerian since all the vertices have even degree, so can we not just skip a few edges and be done...?

I am trying to construct a graph that is 2-connected, planar, has minimum degree 4, and is non-Hamiltonian, but I cannot seem to get the non-Hamiltonian property down for the graph.

In general Eulerian does not imply Hamiltonian, because your graph could have isolated vertices. Even without isolated vertices this implication is not true. For example, you can take two cycles $C_n$ and $C_m$ and identify a common vertex to get a graph on $n+m-1$ vertices and $n+m$ edges. Each vertex has either degree $4$ or $2$, so there is a Eulerian cycle, but there is no Hamiltonian cycle.

It is Hamiltonian. Spoilers below:

 

